# Image sizes for iPhone are incorrect-

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have this image called image.png - I have created it in the 3 differen't sizes.

- image@3x.png - 1001x132px
- image@2x.png - 668x88px
- image.png - 334x44px

What I dont understand is how come the @2x is 668px in width, when the iPhone 5&5S are only 640px wide?

I have designed the @3x using iPhone 6+ screen size.

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain you the difference between the iPhone screens, so you will understand the need of these @?x suffixes.
The first iPhone, and the two after it (3G and 3GS) had the standard display with dimensions `w:320, h:480`. With the introducing of iPhone 4, Apple also introduced the so called **Retina display**, which "packs" 4 physical pixels in 1 logical pixel (also called "point"), i.e.:
[image: Retina display]

Now, even though the pixel dimensions of the iPhone 4 are `w:640, h:960` (and iPhone 5/5C/5S `w:640, h:1136`), you still have screen size of `w:320, h:480` points (respectively `w:320, h:568` for 5/5C/5S). But because the coordinate system of the display uses points instead of pixels, the dimensions and position in points of all UI elements remains the same for every device.

### What about the prefixes?

Now, the ratio between point and pixels is called "scale". UIScreen, UIView, UIImage, and CALayer classes have a property called `scale`, and when you load image with prefix `@2x`, the scale will be `2.0` and the display will fit 2x2 bitmap pixels from the image in one point. iPhone 6+ uses the `@3x` suffix because of the Retina HD display, which has scaling factor `3` and the image is afterwards downscaled from rendered 2208 × 1242 pixels to 1920 × 1080 pixels (points on the screen).

> The downscaling ratio is 1920 / 2208 = 1080 / 1242 = 20 / 23. That
>   means every 23 pixels from the original render have to be mapped to 20
>   physical pixels. In other words the image is scaled down to
>   approximately 87% of its original size.

([source](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified)).

### Required image sizes

For example if you want to have an image of green circle in a black square with dimensions `w:100, h:100`, you will need two more images: one with dimensions `w:200, h:200` and one with `w:300, h:300`, as the system will scale them according to the suffix.
[image]

### Where to go next

Here is some stuff to read (if I didn't explain it right or easy to understand). My advice: check the link above and the official Apple documentation for further knowledge:

[Apple documentation: Supporting high-res devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html)

[Apple documentation: Points vs. Pixels](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH14-SW7)

Comment: Great answer. But what I did not get out of that answer was, what to do then? If I understood correctly from other tutorials, I create the image in the @3x scale(iPhone 6+) size, and render the other 2 scales? How would I design the image then, since it needs to have a certain size compared to the screen.

Comment: If your original image is `100x100 pixels`, the @2x version should be `200x200` and @3x should be `300x300`. Here is an example for scale `1.0` and `2.0`:
[CLICK HERE](http://browserfame.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/retina-display-firefox.png) to see example.

The left circle is 100x100 on retina display: it's blurry and doesn't look sharp. The right one is 200x200 and is scaled to the needed 100x100 pixels. And you see the difference: the right one looks exactly like the original, though it's twice the dimensions of it.

Comment: I updated my original answer. I hope this time I helped you (and you mark my first ever "Correct answer" :D )

Comment: Since I design in the iPhone 6+ screen (1242x2208) I make the @ 3x first (e.g. 300x300) and then down scale for both scales. And that is what I have done in my question(^^) its scaled down, so it should work? But it doesn't as you can see the @ 2x is larger than the Retina display in pixels. But the @ 3x fits fine (1001px in width)

Comment: You are mistaking the bitmap pixels of the jpg/png files with the points on the screen. For every suffix divide the width and height by the number of the suffix: Image with 300x300 and suffix `@3x` will take 100x100 points on the display. Image with 200x200 and suffix `@2x` will take 100x100 points on the display. Image with 100x100 and no suffix will take 100x100 points on the display.

Comment: In all three cases you have the same sized image on every display. In your case `image.png - 334x44px` on old iPhone (i.e. 3g, 3gs) will look exactly the same as the `image@2x.png - 668x88px` on Retina display phone (4, 4s, 5, 5c, 5s, 6) and both will look exactly the same as the `image@3x.png - 1001x132px` on iPhone 6+. Check the divisions: `668 /2 = 334 | 88 /2 = 44` for @2x and `1001 /3 = 333.33 ~334 | 132 /3 = 44` for @3x.
Got it now? :)

Answer (score 0):

@2x is using for retina display, like iphone 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 6, ipads ....
The image has 668px in width, I think it use for a view that could have extra area for view, like horizontal scroll view, tutorial pages, or for ipad ... ... or something like that ..
And yes, you're right about the width of retina display, it is just 640px. 
Hope this may help.